# inline implementation and function calling showing two different behavior in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to implement the `delete function` for `singly linked list`.

My implementation is as follow.

```
typedef struct singly_linked_list{
    int data;
    struct singly_linked_list *next;
}sll;
```

Function to delete first node is as follow:

```
void delete_node_from_front(sll ** head){
    sll ** temp;
    *temp = *head;
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
    (*temp)->next = NULL;
    free_node(temp);
}
```

Another function from where I am calling this function:

```
void delete_node_from_given_pos(sll ** head, int pos){
    int i = 1;
    sll * temp;
    sll * prev;
    temp = *head;
    prev = *head;
    if(pos == 1){
        delete_node_from_front(head);
    }
    else{
        while(temp != NULL && i < pos){
            i++;
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp != NULL){
            prev->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
            free_node(&temp);
        }
        else{
            printf("Node with given position is not present");
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is giving me `segmentation fault`.

But If I replace the function call `delete_node_from_front()` in the imlementation of `delete_node_from_given_pos()` by the below code

```
(*head) = (*head)->next;
temp->next = NULL;
free_node(&temp);
```

program `runs perfectly`. The way I am calling the fucntion:

```
sll * head;
head = NULL;
int arr[_SIZE]=_ELEMENT;
create_list(&head, arr, _SIZE);
delete_node_from_given_pos(&head, 1);
print_list(head);
```

Implementation of `print_list` function

```
void print_list(sll * head){
    int i = 0;
    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head =  head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

implementation of `free_node` function:

```
void free_node(sll ** head){
    free(*head);
}
```

What could be the possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: Your delete_node_from_front function exhibits undefined behaviour; where does temp point to?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Head of the linked list. Is the initialization *temp = *head is wrong?? What should be the proper way then?

Comment: `*temp = *head;` is wrong. `temp` is uninirialize. `*temp = *head;` should be `sll *temp = *head;`

Comment: when working with 'pointers' and 'pointer to pointers' it helpes me to take a piece of paper and paint boxes (malloced memory), arrows (next pointers) and named arrows (pointer variables). so `ssl ** temp` would paint as a box (one ssl), an arrow to the box with unnamed variable (or named `*temp`) and another arrow pointing to this unnamed variable with label `temp`. And that shows: you would need to malloc memory for this unnamed `*temp`, iff you would need that construct.